# Ajuda validacao formulario ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, ios, typescript, ionic3

gostaria de uma pequena ajuda , sou novo no ionic , e gostaria de uma ajuda na validacoes de email so para ve se ele e valido , nao quero buscar em nenhum banco de dados , so quero saber se ele tem @ ou .com algo assim 
imagem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahbo5.jpg

Código :

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding id="register" style="background-image: url(assets/imgs/background.png)">
<div class="register">
<img src="assets/imgs/logo_azul.png" />
<p style="color :#FFFAFA; margin-left: 30%"> Crie sua conta
</p>
</div>
<form class="" action="index.html" method="post">

<ion-item id="box">
<ion-label floating><ion-icon name="ios-contact-outline"></ion-icon> Nome completo</ion-label>

<ion-input ></ion-input >
</ion-item>
<ion-item id="box">
<ion-label floating> <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline"></ion-icon> Email</ion-label>
<ion-input type="email" style="text-decoration: underline"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item id="box">

<ion-label floating> <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> Senha</ion-label>

<ion-input type="password"></ion-input>

</ion-item>
<ion-item id="box">

<ion-label floating> <ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon> Confirmar senha</ion-label>

<ion-input type="password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<button ion-button color="branco" round style="width: 120px" (click)="cancelar()">Cancelar</button>
<button ion-button color="branco" round style="width: 120px">Criar conta</button>
</form>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: <ion-input type="email" email style="text-decoration: underline"></ion-input>

Comment: veja se funciona